# How Create Gradle sharedManifest for multiple projects?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, java-ee-7, build.gradle

I have multiple java projects. these projects are creating jar,war and ear files using gradle. In each project I have used manifest file to maintain the meta data like version,date-time...
Fro this I have included the manifest file creation logic in every build.gradle file.

```
manifest {
     attributes( 
    'Bundle-Vendor' : "$BUNDLE_VENDOR",
    'Build-Time': new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")) 
}
```

But in Gradle there is a feature call **sharedManifest**. I have defined the bellow two tasks in main project **build.gradle** script. But in the every jar and war file have the default MANIFEST.MF file created by Gradle.

```
ext.sharedManifest = manifest {

    attributes( 
        'Bundle-Vendor' : "$BUNDLE_VENDOR", 
         'Build-Time': new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
     ) 
}

task fooJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest = project.manifest {
        from sharedManifest
    }
}

task fooWar(type: War) {
    manifest = project.manifest {
        from sharedManifest
    }
}
```

jar.manifest.writeTo("/MANIFEST.MF")
war.manifest.writeTo("/MANIFEST.MF")

please can some one give the suggestion how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to share manifest logic within a build is a configuration rule such as:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Jar) { // includes War and Ear
        manifest {
            attributes ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this code in my main project build.gradle file like  this allprojects {
    tasks.withType(War) {
        manifest {
            attributes( 
   'Bundle-Vendor' : "$BUNDLE_VENDOR",
            'Build-Time': new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            ) 
        }
    }
}  but it manifest file I can see only Manifest-Version: 1.0

Comment: Your snippet works just fine for me. Either you are looking in the wrong place (note that you used `withType(War)` which doesn't include Jars and Ears), or something else is wrong with your build.

Comment: Hi Peter, If I used above code snippet do I want to use war.manifest.writeTo("/MANIFEST.MF") write the manifest in to sub-projects or it is automatically override the default manifest file. In my case I cant override or replace the default manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is another way to create a shared manifest:

Create a java.gradle file to keep configurations for Java subprojects and put inside:

```
ext.sharedManifest = manifest {
    attributes(
.......
    )
}
```

Then, in the root build.gradle apply this configuration for subprojects

```
subprojects {
    apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/java.gradle"
.....
}
```

And there is possible to reuse this shared manifest and add extra attributes:

Subproject A:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        from sharedManifest
        attributes(
                'JavaFX-Application-Class': 'com.main.SomeClass',
.....
        )
    }
}
```